# Passing a string in VBScript to a COM Function which expects a BSTR*

Tags: vbscript, bstr

I calling a third-party COM function in my VBScript. The method signature is as follows:

```
HRESULT  ParseXML ([in] BSTR *textIn,[in] VARIANT_BOOL *aValidateIn,[out, retval] MSXML2.IXMLDOMDocument2 **aXMLDocOut)
```

In my VBScript the following call gives back a type mismatch:

```
Dim someText
someText = "Hello"
Dim response
response = ParseXml(someText, False)
```

But passing in the string literal works fine:

```
Dim response
response = ParseXml("Hello", False)
```

Any ideas what I need to do on the VBScript side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BSTR` is already a pointer.
`BSTR*` is therefore a pointer to pointer.

That is, you are passing a string by reference (`ByRef textIn As String`).

When you pass a variable by reference, the types must match. `someText` is `VARIANT`.

If you were to pass just `BSTR` (`ByVal textIn As String`), VB would handle the conversion for you.

> Any ideas what I need to do on the VBScript side?

If you are sure it's the script you want to fix, not the library, then trick VB into using a temp variable which will be passed by ref:

```
response = ParseXml((someText), False)
```

Comment: Thanks, updating the script using the temp variable worked fine. It's a third-party lib so updating the library wasn't an option. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you really write `ParseXml(somText, False)` in your script? Then it is a typo; it should be `someText`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when writing the question, no typo existed in the actual script.